# Show MKMapView using a dynamic radius

Tags: iphone, ios, mkmapview, mapkit

I am stuck with a problem. I have tried a lot options but could not get the exact result required. My requirement is as follows:

I have to show an annotation pins for a set of users.  I'm fetching the users from a web service and getting their latitude and longitude and I am able to show them on the map perfectly. However,  the user can choose to show only those users who are within radius of 1000 meter (1 KM) of themselves.

The map should zoom so that only those users who are within the 1KM should show (possibly zoom further so that if all users are within a radius of less than 1KM the zoom will be the maximum distance from the furthest user).

How can I accomplish this with MKMapView?

Thanks in advance.

Abhishek

Comment: What options have you tried and what was the result?  Have you tried using MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This website has a really useful guide on setting zoom levels:

http://troybrant.net/blog/2010/01/set-the-zoom-level-of-an-mkmapview/